# how to compute a^x %p

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

Hi I want to calculate $a^x mod p$ where p is prime and $x$ is large. What I know is that since $p$ is prime, it forms a cyclic group with order $p$ ie $ a^p$ $mod$ $p = a$. Thus, my problem will be easier if I do $x = $$t $ $mod(p-1) $ and then compute $a^t$ $mod$ $p$. But while computing my $x$ in the earlier stage i have expression like
$x = c(2n,n)^b$  which i can compute only by using modular inverse. since here $(p-1) $ is not prime( actually an even number ) I cannot proceed with it. Can anybody help to find any progress in this.

Comment: Do you need some theoretical answers? Actual  effective calculations are normally done e.g. with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method

Comment: @gammatester but in my case $x$ is large, I cannot store it before reducing by mod operation means it will be more tha $10^{30}$

Comment: You only need about $\log(10^{30}) \approx 200$ operations, and the reductions are done at every step. The only requirement is that you can deal with numbers up to $p^2$.

Comment: but where will i store this number, I can only use primitive data types available, i can afford only number less than $10^{18}$

Comment: @gammatester As I have told i am computing $x$ using some formula ( i have given an example in the question), i can reduce x while computing it only

Comment: You should give some more information, how you get $x$. If you can compute it's bit sequence you are done. If $x=\sum y_k$ you compute $a^x \equiv \prod a^{y_k} \pmod p$ etc.

Comment: @gammatester sorry for inconvenience, I have given actual formula for x. Please take a look

Comment: What do you mean by $c(2n,n)$; is this by any means supposed to be the binomial coefficient $\binom{2n}n$? And what is the exponent $b$?

Comment: If $\gcd(a,p)=1$ you have with $\varphi(p)=p-1$
$$a^x \equiv a^{(x \;\bmod \; \varphi(p))} \pmod p.$$ You can compute $x \;\bmod \; (p-1))$ with the discussed methods.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen yes c(2n,n) is binomial coefficient. Yes i want to do the same but inorder to compute $xmod(p-1)$ i need to find $(n!mod(p-1))^{-1}$. Thats the problem i am facing.

Comment: @thetatheta The value $({n!}\pmod{p-1})^{-1}$ is actually not well defined if $n!$ has common divisor with $(p-1)$. However, it's possible to evaluate the binomial coefficient modulo any number (check [Lucas Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem)). That being said; could you provide some ranges for the numbers you're dealing with? (e.g. $1000$, $10^9$, ...?)

Comment: @PeterKošinár constraints are $n,b,a <=10^5$

Comment: @PeterKošinár Can we use chinese remainder theorem here?
Like split (p-1) into prime factors $k_{1}^{n1}, k_{2}^{n2},$etc and then compute $C(2n,n)$ $mod$ $k_{i}^{n_i}$ for each factor and then combine the result.. I am not sure of this? will  u plz verify

Comment: @thetatheta Indeed so; the Chinese Remainder Theorem should do the trick.

Comment: **Please** ask the specific question you are after, not some roundabout way of getting there. I'd suggest you abandon this one, and ask what you really are after, *step by step*. Note that there are several libraries than allow computation with large numbers (hundreds of digits).

Answer (score 3):

The real problem here seems to be to compute the value of the (central) binomial coefficient $\binom{2n}n$ modulo an integer $m$ (where $m+1$ is the prime number $p$, but this gives us little useful information about the factorisation of $m$, except that it $m$ is almost certainly composite).

Since you did not say that the prime $p$ was huge, I'll suppose that it is feasible to find the factorisation of $m=p-1$ effectively. Even if this is not the case, you might be able to proceed by ignoring any remaining divisor$~D$ of$~m$ for which you checked that $D$ has no prime factors less than $2n$, because $\tbinom{2n}n$ is guaranteed to be invertible modulo$~D$, and the inverse can effectively be computed using the extended Euclidean algorithm. For the prime factors $q<2n$ of $m$,  [Kummer's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_theorem) is your friend (though I guess you could get its result here by direct reasoning as well, if you had not heard about it before). It tells you that you can find the multiplicity of $q$ as factor of $\tbinom{2n}n$ by performing the addition $n+n$ numerically in base $q$ representation, and paying attention to any carries that may be generated; the number of carries gives the multiplicity you are after. Once the powers of such $q$ are dealt with, you can find the remaining factor of $\tbinom{2n}n$ by taking the fraction
$$
  \frac{2n(2n-1)(2n-2)\ldots(n+1)}{n(n-1)(n-2)\ldots1} \tag1
$$
and dividing each factor by the largest powers of such $q$ possible; the remaining quotient of products can be computed directly modulo $m$, since everything has become relatively prime to $m$.

The "direct reasoning" above amounts to simply keeping track of the factors $q$ you are simplifying by, and multiplying the end result by any excess power that was removed from the numerator but not from the denominator. Come to think of it, you can do this using only very basic theory: simply write every factor in$~(1)$ as product of all the prime factors it has common with$~m$, and a remaining part that is relatively prime with $m$; then perform separate computations for the "common" and "relatively prime" parts. Warning: the "product of common prime factors with $m$"  of a number need not be equal to its GCD with$~m$ (it could be larger); nonetheless it can be found by repeated GCD computations.